# CefSharp choose local end point

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp How can I choose (wireless, ethernet 0, ethernet 1, etc) network adaptor per a ChromiumWebBrowser.

Sample:
ChromiumWebBrowser browser1 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("blabla com"); // Browse with my "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" (Ethernet 1)

ChromiumWebBrowser browser2 = new ChromiumWebBrowser("newblabla com"); // Browse with my "Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165" (Wi-Fi)

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you can do that, Chromium uses just TCP for communications, routing through different adapters is done at the O.S. level

Comment: Potentially you could implement `IRequestHandlerFactory` and `IRequestHandler` then use `.Net` to perform all of your web requests. That's assuming you can select which endpoint the request is bound to in `.Net`. There are examples in the `GitHub` project source, make sure you select the branch to the version your using as they're been rewritten lately, so you'll need an example that matches your version.

Comment: @amaitland Thank you for your comment.